# Use camera as overlay for uiview iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

I was wondering if it was possible to make the camera feed appear in a custom screen. Basically I have a uiview that I want the camera feed to appear in. I would then have custom buttons on the screen and stuff like that to take pictures and then email out the pictures.

Is there an easy way to do this, that will not get rejected upon app review? I have read before about using UIImagePicker and using cameraOverlayView, but I could not get that to work.

Sample code is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use [AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009524) from the AVFoundation framework.

Comment: Is there any easy way to capture an image from this?

Comment: You can use [AVCaptureStillImageOutput](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureStillImageOutput_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009552).